# Hibernate mapping between PostgreSQL array of enum and Kotlin Set of enum

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, enums

In a Kotlin project, using Spring Boot, Flyway, PostgreSQL, and Hibernate as an **ORM**

I'am trying to add a new column in a `creators` table, the column should hold an array of an **ENUM** (`AUDIENCE`).

Flyway migration

```sql
CREATE TYPE AUDIENCE AS ENUM ('VAL1', 'VAL2');

CREATE CAST (VARCHAR AS AUDIENCE) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;

ALTER TABLE creators
    ADD COLUMN audiences AUDIENCE[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{VAL1}',
    ADD CONSTRAINT ck__creators__audiences CHECK (cardinality(audiences) > 0);
```

Audience.kt

```kotlin
enum class Audience {
    VAL1,
    VAL2
}
```

Creator.kt

```kotlin
@Column(columnDefinition = "_AUDIENCE[]")
@Convert(converter = AudiencesArrayConverter::class)
val audiences: Set<Audience> = emptySet(),
```

AudienceArrayConverter.kt

```kotlin
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
import javax.persistence.Converter

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class AudiencesArrayConverter : AttributeConverter<Set<Audience>, Array<String>> {

    override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(audiences: Set<Audience>): Array<String> =
        audiences.map(Audience::name).toTypedArray()

    override fun convertToEntityAttribute(column: Array<String>): Set<Audience> =
        column.map(Audience::valueOf).toSet()
}
```

The tests that need to fetch some creators from the DB failed with this message:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "audiences" is of type audience[] but expression is of type bytea
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Could someone please help me understand and fix this ?

**Note:** I really don't understand why I needed to add the underscore in

```kotlin
@Column(columnDefinition = "_AUDIENCE[]")
```

So if someone could explain this also, I would be grateful